AWS NLB health checks fails when using docker node app
I'm trying to understand what is happening with my NLB configuration.
I have a network load balancer with a tcp:80 listener and a target group also for tcp:80 for traffic port and tcp for health checks port. I have only one target which is an EC2 instance and configured a simple apache server, which the target is healthy.
The problem is when I run and forward the container port from 80 to 3000, using docker run -p 80:3000 .. then it turns out to be unhealthy.
I don't understand why it works when I configure apache on EC2, but doesn't when the 80 port forwarded to target port 3000 where my app is listening.
I had used ping from a jumpbox to check my EC2 private instance (where I have my dockerized app) and it works, I have used curl and it works, I have used telnet and it works, I even momentarily set the security group to accept all inbound and outbound in my private EC2 instance.
Thinking maybe my load balancer health check denies, but that doesn't make sense to me because when using the apache server it works.
Not sure how to debug and I doubt the docker port mapping changes something I'm not aware of.

Well I dont know what happened but it seems that configuring apache before the docker app messed something, I just recreated the ec2 instance and just deployed the docker app and now it is working
